# Facebook Like Button Text in feed?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

With the facebook iframe like button, am I able to specify what text shows up in a users stream?

When I use a plugin for a wordpress blog post it shows up at

> USERNAMe likes POST TITLE on BLOG NAME

but when I try and put it on another page with the straight up iframe code, i just get:

```
USERNAME likes http://www.pagename.com/bla/bla/bla
```

How can I specify what text shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have open graph tags on your page, like:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="..." /> 
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="..." /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="..." /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="..." /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="..." /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
</head>
```

More about those [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph).